# Заменить символы звездочками - replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения, replace, замена

Нужно в логине емайла скрыть все символы звездочками кроме последней и первой.
Результат:

```
a**********t@domain.com.
```

Как исправить код?

```js
var str = "adminaccount@domain.com";
str = str.replace(/(\S{1})(\S+?)(?=[@])/g, function(a, b, c) {
  return b + c.replace(/./g, '*');
});
console.log(str); // a***********@domain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу меняем по 1 символу, без использования функций. Условия поиска символа для замены: Перед ним не должно быть начала строки (`(?!^)`), после него должен быть один и более символов, за которыми следует @ (`(?=.+@)`):

```js
var str = "adminaccount@domain.com";
str = str.replace(/(?!^).(?=.+@)/g, '*');
console.log(str);   // "a**********t@domain.com"
```

Первым вариантом было: `str.replace(/(?<=.).(?=.+@)/g, '*');` Проверялось не начало строки, а наличие одного символа перед тем, который будет меняться. Но по подсказке @Grundy этот вариант может работать не во всех браузерах, так как упреждающая проверка `?<=` появилась в регулярных выражениях JS недавно.

Comment: `(?<=.)` - вот это может не во всех браузерах работать, можешь через `(?=` ее выразить вторым вариантом? :)

Comment: @Grundy Блин, че у js такие скучные регулярки :( А `(?!^)` будет работать во всех браузерах ?

Comment: ?! да, ?<= только в последних версиях

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, исправлено. Так оно даже проще выглядит

Comment: Надо было две версии оставить :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно захватить в отдельные группы первый символ, всё, что после него до последнего символа перед `@`, затем символ перед последним `@`, а потом снова объединить захваченные строки, заменив вторую группу звёздочками с помощью метода `String#repeat`:

```js
var str = 'adminaccount@domain.com';
console.log(
  str.replace(/^(.)(.*)(.)@/, (_,x,y,z) => `${x}${'*'.repeat(y.length)}${z}@`)
)
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(.)` - Группа №1: один символ, отличный от перевода строки
- `(.*)` - Группа №2:  ноль и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше
- `(.)` - Группа №3: один символ, отличный от перевода строки
- `@` - символ `@`

Answer (score 0):

- добавил в регулярное выражение `(\S{1})` и переменную d в функцию, вроде работает корректно

```js
var str = "adminaccount@domain.com";
str = str.replace(/(\S{1})(\S+?)(\S{1})(?=[@])/g, function(a, b, c, d) {
    return b + c.replace(/./g, '*') + d;
});
console.log(str); // a***********t@domain.com
```